# kubectl apply -k URL

Tags: minikube, kustomize, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to install kubeflow pipeline on minikube with the following

```
export PIPELINE_VERSION=1.7.0
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/applications.app.k8s.io
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/env/platform-agnostic-pns?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
```

I want to look into what is being applied with the -k option. I thought the string `"github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"` refers to a URL and input that to a browser and got a 404. So what does the url string mean? How do I find out the content that reside at the location of the url?

Comment: Which version of “kubectl” are you using? What OS are you using?

Comment: (base) ~/ml $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-07T18:08:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
I am using macOS.

Answer (score 1):

The url turns out to be a go-better format url. See https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter#url-format for more details.

Kustomize is built into kubectl. `kubectl apply -k` acts the same as `kustomize build path/to/some/app | kubectl apply -f -`.